# Is there any use of finite metrics on $\mathbb{R}$ or extended real numbers $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, metric-spaces

So in my grad level Real Analysis course based on Mesaure Theory and Lebesgue Integration, our professor added a note stating that extended real numbers $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ can be used with a finite metric by defining

\begin{equation} \rho (x, y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y| \text{ on }\mathbb{R}\end{equation}

and extended with the values

\begin{equation} f(\infty) := \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\arctan(x) = \pi/2 \end{equation}

\begin{equation} f(-\infty) := \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\arctan(x) = -\pi/2 \end{equation}
which results
\begin{equation} \rho (x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)| \text{ on }\mathbb{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} \end{equation}

Here $\rho$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ since the extended $f$ is still injective and it is bounded by $\pi$ in absolute value. So both versions are examples of finite metrics. This was a basic practice in Metric Spaces class of course.

My question is whether or not considering $\mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ gives us any useful theorems or tools. I presume that it could be related to integration which would make lots of integrals finite and integrable considering measure spaces produced by such metrics $\rho$ or functions $f$.

---